# NHibernate - simple join query

Tags: nhibernate, join

A very simple scenario.
I have 2 classes: ***Project*** and ***DataStructure***. Class ***Project*** contains member List<***DataStructure***>. 
My goal is to load a Project and all its DataStructures in one call.

```
public class Project
{
    public virtual string Id { get { } set { } }
    public virtual string Name { get { } set { } }
    public virtual ISet<DataStructure> DataStructures { get { } set { } }
}

public class DataStructure
{
    public virtual string Id { get { } set { } }
    public virtual string Name { get { } set { } }
    public virtual string Description { get { } set { } }
    public virtual Project Project { get { } set { } }
    public virtual IList<DataField> Fields { get { } set { } }
}
```

Note that ***DataStructure*** also contains a list of class ***DataField*** but I don’t want to load these right now.

Mapping in Fluent NHibernate:

```
public class ProjectMap : ClassMap<Project>
{
    public ProjectMap()
    {
        Table("PROJECTS");
        Id(x => x.Pk, "PK");
        Map(x => x.Id, "ID");
        Map(x => x.Name, "NAME");
        HasMany<DataStructure>(x => x.DataStructures).KeyColumn("FK_PROJECT");
    }
}

public class DataStructureMap : ClassMap<DataStructure>
{
    public DataStructureMap()
    {
        Table("DATA_STRUCTURES");
        Map(x => x.Id, "ID");
        Map(x => x.Name, "NAME");
        Map(x => x.Description, "DESCRIPTION");
        References<Project>(x => x.Project, "FK_PROJECT");
        HasMany<DataField>(x => x.Fields).KeyColumn("FK_DATA_STRUCTURE");
    }
}
```

This is my query:

```
using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("from Project left join DataStructure");
    project = query.List<Project>();
}
```

The result is this exception:

```
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.SemanticException: Path expected for join! [from Themis.DataEntities.Project left join DataStructure]
```

Do I need to specify the field for the join? Isn’t that inferred from the mappings?

Note1 – Table ***PROJECTS*** contains a single ***Project*** row so there is no need to search for a specific one.

Note2 – I verified that my NHibernate setup is correct by successfully loading just the ***Project***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is interested I found the answer on nhusers:

```
IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("from Project as pr left join pr.DataStructures")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be `"from Project left join Project.Fields"`. `Project.DataStructures` is the path that NH expects to see. Remember that it's object oriented, not table oriented, so most of the time even your queries operate on objects.

Comment: Good answer, but I think you mean `Project.DataStructures`, which I would correct for you if I had the rep.

Comment: I changed the query to IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("from Project left join Project.DataStructures"); Now I get a slightly  different error: NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.InvalidPathException: Invalid path: 'Project.DataStructures' [from Themis.DataEntities.Project left join Project.DataStructures]

Comment: Try specifying namespace for Project.DataStructures too like `Themis.DataEntities.Project.DataStructures`